# how to resolve 'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'strip' issue?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I want to add or raise a validation registration form but I get this error: **'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'strip'** how can I skip it?

I'm suffering from these issues please if you could tell me the correct way to validate the registration form after you solve this problem I'll be appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
class SignUp(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.error_messages = {
            'username_match': 'username is already exist',
            'email_match': 'Email is already exist',
            'password_mismatch': 'these two password isn\'t match try again'
        }
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    # password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    # password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password1',
                  'password2',
                  'email']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['email_match'],
            )
        return email

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            return forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['username_match'],
            )
        return username

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            return forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    form = SignUp(None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:login')
        return form.errors
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**Edit with a new issue:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al3/website/accounts/views.py", line 73, in register
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 168, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/media/medo/BE4C6BE74C6B98C3/Cources/Django/all git/Django projects/Es2al/Es2al2/website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 244, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 207; 2 is required
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not *return* a `ValidationError`, but *`raise`* it. By `return`ing it, the Form assumes that the result of `username`, etc. are `ValidationError`s:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(  # ← raise instead of return
            self.error_messages['email_match'],
        )
    return email
```

This principle should be applied to *all* the `clean_…` methods.

In your view, you can furthermore *not* return `form.errors`, or at least not direclty, you can `print` the `form.errors`, and pass these to a context, but a view should return a `HttpResponse` object:

```
def register(request):
    form = SignUp()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:login')
        # return form.errors
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I was using raise indeed before using return but I got 'ErrorDict' object has no attribute 'status_code' then I thought it was the problem so, how can I resolve it?

Comment: @MedoAbdin: you should not return `form.errors` either :)

Comment: ok @Willem but how can I show errors if I wouldn't return form.errors?
I will post the new issue now thanks for help.

Comment: @MedoAbdin: if you render the form that has been validated, it will render the exceptions. This is done automatically if you render it as `{{ form }}`, if you render the fields manually, the [*Django documentation*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) specifies how to render field errors.

Comment: actually, the first issue I spent a lot of time to resolve and I didn't is that: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 207; 2 is required, the same error is raising when I do what do you tell me to do now so How can I fix it?

Comment: could you allow me to edit the post with a new issue I face to help me?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64671476/edit) the question. Can you provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: @MedoAbdin: it looks like the error is in the template that is rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224068/discussion-between-medo-abdin-and-willem-van-onsem).